# return value without modifiying

Tags: java

I am using Setter getter method in my app. My class that contains setter&getter is:

```
public class Product {

    private  ArrayList<Integer> id=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public ArrayList<Integer> getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ArrayList<Integer> id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class Check extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Integer> passedid=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkout_page);

        Intent checkoutintent=getIntent();
        Intent shopcart=getIntent();

        Product prodobj=new Product();
        passedid=prodobj.getId();   

        new LongRunningGetIO().execute();   
    }
}
```

When I want to use getId() method with object of product class, it is returning every time null value. Is there any way to return the id value which was stored in setId() method.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It should be - I think you should post the code that uses those methods.

Comment: This code looks fine, are you sure you want it to be an arrayList though?  Are you definitely calling the set first?

Comment: I have edited my question have look please.

Comment: Seriously nobody bothered to tag this with the language? At all? None of you? Especially @lokoko who simply removed the [android] tag and left the question as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to return the id value which was stored in setId()
>   method.

I'm little confused from your approach. You want to get particular id from your List but you are returning whole List. What about to return parcitular integer from your List? Then you need to implement method for adding values to List.

> it is returning every time null value

Your List cannot be returned as **`NULL`** since in your code you initilised it.

### Update:

```
ArrayList<Integer> passedid = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Product prodobj = new Product();
passedid = prodobj.getId();
```

This absolutely doesn't make a sence. Look, here you are created new ArrayList passedid that is empty then it's assigned with next empty ArrayList.

If you want to pass data via Intents you need to use Intent's methods:

```
putIntegerArrayListExtra(key, value) // for putting data to Intent
getIntegerArrayListExtra(key) // retrieving data from Intent
```

> can you suggest me with any changes in my Product class that which is
>   posted in my question

So probably you want to add items to your List so you need to create method for achieve this goal:

```
public void add(int item) {
   this.id.add(item);
}
```

Or just create some ArrayList, fill up with values and then use your setter as well:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(3);
Product product = new Product();
product.setId(list);
```

Comment: thanq Sajmon.Actually my job is to set id value from number of classes & use the entire arraylist in another class as edited in my question.

Comment: yes Sajmon your right.but when i put code like this:public ArrayList<Integer> getId() { Log.d("id at get",""+id);
        return id;
    } in my logcat(debug) it is showing [].

Comment: @SHAIKAFEEZA in your case this always return non null ArrayList since, you initialised it.

Comment: can you suggest me with any changes in my Product class that which is posted in my question.

Comment: thanq Sajmon I got solution that ArrayList<Integer> id = new ArrayList<Integer>(); change to ArrayList<Integer> id; in my Product class.